# Using amp script in non-amp page

Tags: amp-html

There are side effects using script amp in standard html5 pages?

My idea is to use amp-iframe to show some related content, also in web pages and not only in amp pages.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried some month ago.
My idea was to use the `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js`  to load images async for performance.

Same to use the [flying carpet](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-fx-flying-carpet/) and the [Carousel](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/) on my regular site. The result was the internal validator brings to much errors, the script breaks, you need the Boilerplate and so on.

So the answer is **you can't use the AMP** script on a 'normal' HTML site. Or you take the script and modify it for you. But you will lost the on going support of all changes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen side effects yet of a nonamp/amp hybrid page. I'm currently using  https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js for img control (ex: lazy load) on a non amp page.

I'll guess this is not the type of bad coding that Google will result in a rank penalty.

My nonamp page has:

- Link tag to refer to the real amp page.
- Google Chrome detects it's nonamp page and suggests the amp page
  version.
- No boilerplate.
- Used nonamp analytics.
- Did not use thunderbolt or amp in html tag.

Images didn't show up on Blu windows 8 phone. Suspect amp script at fault.
Images **do** show up on Android smartphone.